# Do community wiki votes count towards the Mortarboard badge?

Tags: discussion, badges, voting, community-wiki, daily-reputation-badges

You can still get the Mortarboard badge on Meta sites, even though you get no reputation.

Do votes on Community Wiki posts count towards this as well? Should they?